# Newly tiled shower leaking white liquid

Tags: tile, ceramic-tile, leaks

I recently remodeled the bathroom in my 1910 craftsman. We pulled out give layers of rotten subfloor and fixed a leaking sewage pipe, then had a tiler make a new shower.

When he was done there was a strange slightly raised bit that you can see in the attached picture. He said he was unable to get this leveled but it shouldn't be a problem.

It was working fine for about a week, and then over the last couple of days I've noticed a strange white liquid leaking from that strange bump. And I can push down a few of the mosaic tile with my finger which makes me think it's mushy under there.

I don't even know where to start on fixing this and would appreciate any advice about what might be causing it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you called the tile contractor to come back and have a look? Is there a reason there isn't any sort of sealant (caulk) in the gap where the wall meets the floor? Was this supposed to set for a while before he came back to finish it, and you've been using it in the mean time?

Comment: The tile should not be moving AT ALL!  There is a problem here, get the installer back to correct it work but I believe it's going to involve tearing it out, resolving the problem in the substrate, and re-installing the tile.  The white stuff looks like "stale" caulk that was used, didn't cure, and is now dissolving due to moisture.  It's all BAD here!

Comment: Yeah, this is a contractual issue and not something we can help with. The tile needs to be removed and redone. Whatever that is clearly prevents proper bonding and stability of your tile.